# CronR runs only once (frequency set to minutely), then doesn't run anymore afterwards

Tags: r, cron

I've included the code for 2 example scripts, the 1st one is meant to run every minute and output a file and the 2nd script should launch the cron job at a specified time. It works for the first time, however no new files get output after every consecutive minute passes.

A lot of issues other Cron related queries that I found had was related to not using absolute filepaths. I use the 'normalizePath' function which should mean this is not the issue however I dont know what else to consider.

"Script_to_be_scheduled.R" - Create's and outputs a file:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

csv_table <- data.table(bla = sample(1:1000, size = 15) )

filepath <- "~/My-Local-Workspace"
filename <- paste0("automaticTable__", hour(Sys.time()), "_", minute(Sys.time()), "_", round(second(Sys.time())), ".csv")
filepath_full <-  paste0(normalizePath(filepath), "/", filename)

fwrite(csv_table, file = filepath_full  )

> filepath_full
[1] "/home/redacted/redacted/My-Local-Workspace/Script_to_be_scheduled.R"
```

"Scheduler_test.R" - Create's and schedules the cron job to run every minute once a specified time is reached:

```
library("cronR")

filepath <- "~/My-Local-Workspace"
filename <- "Script_to_be_scheduled.R"
filepath_full <-  paste0(normalizePath(filepath), "/", filename)

commnd <- cron_rscript( filepath_full )

cron_add(command = commnd, 
         frequency = 'minutely', 
         id = 'This is the title', 
         at = '14:56', 
         description = 'My process 1', 
         tags = c('Algorithm_1'))
```

Comment: Have you looked at the log?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's very unhelpful as the only thing in there is the messages produced from initially loading the libraries. That means no errors get encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've done some more digging and finally found the issue, it looks like it's due to a bug.

I came across this explanation when I started researching how to use the linux terminal to schedule the jobs instead of R https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux

> The cron and at services enable sysadmins to schedule tasks to run at
> a specific time in the future. The at service specifies a one-time
> task that runs at a certain time. The cron service can schedule tasks
> on a repetitive basis, such as daily, weekly, or monthly

Based on this I thought that maybe specifying both the 'frequency' and the 'at' variable within cronR could be the issue and turns out that this was the case. After commenting out the 'at' argument, my script started running each minute as I wanted it to. The documentation gives examples where both arguments are used together however which makes me think its either a bug, or a warning should be produced by the package informing you of this hidden interaction.

I was using cronR version 0.4.2